# Keeping GH homepage in sync with README.md

Tags: github, github-pages

While creating GitHub Pages for my project I was suggested to import existing `README.md` as the project's homepage. Later, I merged `gh-pages` with `master` and ended up with both `index.html` and `README.md`.

The "problem" is that the updates to `README.md` won't affect `index.html`. Is there any simple way to keep them in sync? Preferably with zero Jekyll knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, in case someone is interested.

Typically I write HTML using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) preprocessor, and luckily it does support [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) which is the language `README.md` is written in. So my steps where as following:

1. Translate `index.html` generated by GH Pages to Jade. I used online [`html2jade`](http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com) tool;
2. Save the output to `index.jade`;
3. Locate `section` block in the resulting markup in `index.jade` and replace its entire content with:

   `section
       include:md README.md`
4. Run `jade index.jade` which produces new, automatically generated `index.html`;
5. Commit both files to `gh-pages`.

See example in [this](https://github.com/the-happy-hippo/sprits-it/commit/1d648be6cac76b8bc3b7ea4e9b622832202fd723) commit on GitHub.